# Openssl is not working for windows 2016

Tags: windows, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, windows-server-2016

Even after setting the environment path , the openssl command is not working.
Kindly help me for this.

[image: openssl]

[image: INSTALLED IN D DRIVE]

[image: ENVIRONMENT ARIABLE]

[image: SET THE PATH FOR OPENSSL]

Comment: Check you CMD env with `set p` and execute you binary EXACTLY withthe path shown there. I am sure there is a path mismatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path of the openssl binary is not `D:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64` as you specified. The openssl binary is inside the `bin` subfolder, i.e. the path need to be set as `D:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin`. Apart from that please note that openssl 0.9.8 is obsolete for many years and the currently supported version is openssl 1.1.1. I don't know what you are trying to do with openssl but this old version does not support newer TLS versions like TLS 1.2 at all.

Comment: Thanks . I tried even with \bin path. But it was not working. Let me try for newer version I want to implement ssl certificate for apache. But for to generate CSR the error is being shown for openssl